# Saving class to file?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am writing a program that is a music player and a lyrics finder. As of now, each time the program loads it has to read each music file and retrieve the ID3 tag to find the artist name, song name, etc. When reading more than a couple files, the process to extract the ID3 tags is very time-consuming. I want to be able to save the ID3 information to my program's private data directory instead of reading each ID3 tag each time the program is ran.

I am confused on serialization and saving/loading something like this. I am guessing I should be using FileOutput/InputStreams or ObjectOutput/InputStreams to achieve this, but I cannot grasp them. Can someone help me out and show me how to save and load my "Song" class correctly? Below are the variables that I need to be able to save.

```
public class Song implements Serializable
{
    private int index = 0, trackLength = 0;
    private Bitmap albumArtwork = null;
    private String toString, name, trackNumber, artist, album, lyrics, fileName, releaseDate;
}
```

As you can see, I need to keep track of some Strings, two ints, and a Bitmap. Can someone show me the setup of how to save an **array** or **ArrayList** of these to a file, say, named "music_info.sav" or something along those lines? Also, how can you check if this file exists (and if it does not, create the file as empty)?

Answer (score 3):

```
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("song.ser"));
    out.writeObject(yourArrayList);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

to write

```
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("song.ser"));
    ArrayList<Song> myArrayList = (ArrayList<Song>) in.readObject();
    in.close();
```

to read.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure about the Bitmap object. You might have to roll your own readObject() and writeObject() method.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
```

Here is a link on serializing and de-serializing bitmaps.

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/06/serializing-and-de-serializing-android-graphics-bitmap/

Comment: Will Bitmap serialize that way? It doesn't implement Serializable.

Comment: @dontoscata -- You're right. I didn't notice the Bitmap object.

Comment: This is how I originally tried to do it. I was still confused. I have 2 questions... 
1. The way you're doing it, the file has to exist. How do I create the file if it does not exist? I suppose you try to make the ObjectInputStream and catch an Exception. If an Exception is caught, make the file (but I don't know how to make this empty file). 
2. How does this change the ObjectInput/OutputStream functions? I don't know where or when you would call writeObject and readObject.

Comment: The file does not have to exist. FileOutputStream will create the file if it doesn't. If it already exists, it will overwrite it. 
Your readObject and writeObject methods will be a part of Serializable class ( in this case Song )

Comment: So I can still call ArrayList<Song> myArrayList = (ArrayList<Song>) in.readObject(); exactly like above and it will implicitly call my readObject method in Song (and the same for writeObject)? This is the part that I am confused on.

Comment: Yes. Thats how objectinputstream / outputstream works. It looks to see if the object has its own writeObject and readObject methods and uses them instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a SQLLite database to store this information instead of rolling your own File serialization.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and see if you can make that works.

Comment: Create a sqlite database and store those fields as columns. This will allow fast access as well sorting/searching abilities.